# How to add line spacing and multiple new lines in react wyswig editor

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I need to have a line spacing option in react WYSIWYG editor, after pressing enter in the editor the default spacing is very large. I need to customize it also if I use shift+ enter it adds a 
 tag in the next line so the text is not aligned.

On multiple enter, it doesn't save the multiple newlines.

Could someone please help how to handle these problem statements?

Answer (score 0):

I just can do that with :

```
 <pre>{`Depatred port : \nnew line\nalot new`}</pre>
```